# Unable to sign out of ADFS 3.0 on IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, adfs, adfs3.0

We have developed an MVC/Angular application that uses ADFS. Since we are using Angular we had to create a wrapper around ADFS to capture the token so we could use it as a claim so angular could have access to it.

Most of the work is done in the following method:

```
 public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationCodeResponsePath"])))
        {
            var authorizationCode = context.Request.Query[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationCodeResponseParameter"]];

            var token = this.RequestToken(
                this.Options.TokenEndpoint,
                new Uri(this.Options.ApplicationUri, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationCodeResponsePath"]),
                this.Options.ClientId,
                authorizationCode);

            var principal = this.ValidateToken(token, this.Options.Audience, this.Options.Issuer, this.Options.Certificate);

            this.AddTokenToPrincipal(principal, token);

            this.SignIn(context.Authentication, principal);

            context.Response.Redirect(this.Options.RedirectPath.Value);
        }
        else if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignOutPath"])))
        {
            if (context.Request.Query.Any(q => q.Key == "post_logout_redirect_uri"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADFS"] + "/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0");
            }
            else
            {
                this.SignOut(context.Authentication);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Essentially on log in we will sign into ADFS, ADFS will try redirect to a specific URL that we capture in the first if block, we take the authorization code and request the token from here adding a claim and then signing in.

The issue is with sign out, the application makes a request to sign out, the url gets captured here in the second block and a sign out request is made which also tries to redirect to the ADFS sign out page. I can see the .AspNet.Federation is expired/removed but on reloading the page the application just requests a new cookie. This works fine on Chrome/Firefox and if I clear the IE of cookies before making the sign out request it will successfully complete sign out. Is there something I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this corrected using the following command:

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache")
```